# Trying to refresh a section and then error

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a site where anyone in management can access the security cams in the different stores.  I have built using iframes so that the manager can choose which store they want.   Once they choose the store, I want the page to refresh every 6 seconds but error out after 3 minutes.   This will keep from streaming data continuously.

So here is what I have, but something isn't right

```
<title>Store #1901(low-rez)</title>
<center><font color ="blue">Store 1901 (<b>Medium</b> / <a    href="tiny.html">Small</a>)</center>


<iframe src="cam1.html" width="380" height="295" frameborder="0" >
</iframe>
<iframe src="cam2.html" width="380" height="295" frameborder="0" >
</iframe>
<iframe src="cam3.html" width="380" height="295" frameborder="0" >
</iframe>
<iframe src="cam4.html" width="380" height="295" frameborder="0" >
</iframe>
<iframe src="cam5.html" width="380" height="295" frameborder="0" >
</iframe>
<iframe src="cam6.html" width="380" height="295" frameborder="0" >
</iframe>
<iframe src="cam7.html" width="380" height="295" frameborder="0" >
</iframe>
<iframe src="cam8.html" width="380" height="295" frameborder="0" >
</iframe>
<iframe src="cam10.html" width="380" height="295" frameborder="0" >
</iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">

var intervalID = 0;

function windowOnInitialize()
{
intervalID = setInterval("refresh()", 6000);
//alert("we were called");
}

var counter = 0;

function refresh()
{
//alert("we got to if statement");
if (counter < 50)
{
    counter++;
    //alert(counter);
    document.getElementById("theId").src="small.html" + Math.random();
 }
else
{
  //alert("");
  alert("Your Time is Up");
  clearInterval(intervalID);

 }
 }

</script>

<body  onload="windowOnInitialize()">



<img id="theId" src="small.html" />
```

I have tried the script above and below the iframe section and it isn't working either place.  I am sorry if this is a repeated question or rather elementary, I am just learning to code.  I have always worked network and not scripting.

Comment: Doc for `setInterval()`: https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval#setinterval

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `setInterval` function expects a function as the first parameter.  You have passed a string "refresh()".  So, change the line `intervalID = setInterval("refresh()", 6000);` to pass the function instead - `intervalID = setInterval(refresh, 6000);`.

[setInterval](http://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval#setinterval)

Comment: Will I need to put this before or after the iframe

Comment: The order can be left exactly as you have it in your example.

Comment: Ok, I tried and it would not work.  I am wanting the refresh function to refresh the parent which will then pull a new image from each webcam.  Each camera is in it's own iframe.    Do i need to put the code in each iframe?

Comment: Did you want the parent document to completely reload, or did you want each individual iframe to reload separately?

Comment: Because all of the frames are already done, I guess i would prefer the whole parent to reload.   So I just tried this code in the parent.       <body  onload="windowOnInitialize()">
<script>
window.setInterval("reload();", 3000);
var counter = 0;

  
function reload() {
    if (counter <20)
        {
            counter++;
            
 document.getElementById("theId").src="small.html" + Math.random();
}
    else
        {
            alert("your time is up");
            clearInterval(intervalID);
        }
        }
</script>






<id="theId" src="small.html" />

Comment: but doing that, as soon as it times out and I click on the alert, it then refreshes again and alerts again.  What I am looking for is that once the alert comes up, the page stops completely until the person actually hits the refresh button

Comment: OK, you need to cancel the setInterval so it doesn't keep repeating.  So, change the first line to var intervalID = window.setInterval(reload, 3000);.

Comment: Wayne- I changed that line, however once someone clicks ok in the message box, then it will continue to run forever without timing out again.